# A question of probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A box contains $N$ tickets numbered $1,2, \cdots , N$. From this box $n$ tickets are drawn without replacement. What is the probability that the largest number drawn is $M$? What if the tickets were drawn with replacement?

For the case "without replacement" I found the answer to be $$\frac {n(M-1)!(N-n)!} {N!(M-n)!}$$ and for the case "with replacement" I found the answer to be $$\frac {\sum \limits_{r=0}^{n-1} n_{P_ r} {{M-1} \choose r}} {N^n}.$$

Are they correct at all? Please check it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's $n_{P_ r}$?

Comment: Answer on first question is correct. For second question you better use $P(X=M)=P(X\leq M)-P(X\leq M-1)$ where $X$ denotes largest number. I cannot recognize the notation that you use.

Comment: $n_{P_r}$ means $\frac {n!} {(n-r)!}$.